# How to create split-page adverts

Tags: floats, positioning

I'm using the `scrbook` to typeset a document and want to dedicate areas of specific pages (e.g. half page horizontally or vertically, quarter page top right or bottom right) for images (in this case, adverts).

If possible, I would prefer to specify pages on which these adverts would be shown independently of the content on these pages.

Text including headings should flow around the adverts. Adverts should be placed at a small offset (3mm) from the page border, independently of the text margins.

I have so far looked at:

- `wrapfig`, however this places the figure next to the next paragraph and inside the text margins
- `minipages`, but here I can't really get them to wrap the way I want and could not place them relative to the page.

As an illustration, I've made a minimal, non-working example:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{scrbook}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\vspace*{\dimexpr-1in-\topmargin-\headsep-\headheight-
\baselineskip+3mm}%
\hspace*{\dimexpr-1in-\oddsidemargin-\parindent-3mm}%
\makebox[\paperwidth][r]{\frame{\rule{\dimexpr0.5\pdfpagewidth-3mm}{\dimexpr0.5\pdfpageheight-3mm}}}
\lipsum
\end{document}
```

[image: non-working example]
This has a number of problems:

- Text does not flow next to the frame
- headings do not get put next to the frame

Comment: The automation of this is going to be difficult and is easier to achieve using some graphic package. Are you okay with manual adjustment of the flow?

Comment: i recommend flofram for anything resembling a newsletter.

Comment: @Werner yes; while automation would be nice to have; it is not a necessity. The document will have around 80 to 90 pages, so it's a bit of a hassle to layout each separately, but still possible.